# Why does this multiple recursion fail over a certain number of recursions?

Tags: swift, macos, recursion

This code adds up all the integers and `number`, however it crashes with `Segmentation fault: 11` (or bad memory access) at `104829` or larger. Why?

```
import Foundation
func sigma(_ m: Int64) -> Int64 {
    if (m <= 0 ) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return m + sigma(m - 1)
    }
}
let number: Int64 = 104829
let answer = sigma(number)
```

**nb:** `sigma(104828) = 5494507206`

Running in terminal on macOS 10.11 on CoreDuo 2 Macbook Pro with 8GB Ram (incase that's relevant!)

Comment: You're probably running out of stack space. Swift doesn't have tail-call elimination.

Comment: works for me on swift REPL but `sigma(104829)` give me 5494612035

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov swift doesn't have tail-call optimizations? what is your source? I am sure swift have it on release build

Comment: @BryanChen I misspoke, it actually does (for some cases). However, this algorithm can't be tail-call optimized, because the result of the recursive call isn't returned directly, but rather added to m first.

Comment: @PeterJNicholls Btw this adds all Integers, not real numbers.

Comment: Bryn: **THAT** is interesting! Why is our outcome different? Is our OS stack allocation different?

Mine (using code in answer) is:
`rlimit(rlim_cur: 8388608, rlim_max: 67104768)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a Stack Overflow. You can get/set the stack size of your current process using [getrlimit(2)/setrlimit(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit). Here's an example usage:

```
import Darwin // Unnecessary if you already have Foundation imported

func getStackByteLimit() -> rlimit? {
    var limits = rlimit()

    guard getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &limits) != -1 else {
        perror("Error with getrlimit")
        return nil
    }

    return limits
}

func setStackLimit(bytes: UInt64) -> Bool {
    guard let max = getStackByteLimit()?.rlim_max else { return false }

    var limits = rlimit(rlim_cur: bytes, rlim_max: max)

    guard setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &limits) != -1 else {
        perror("Error with setrlimit")
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

By default, it's `8,388,608` bytes, (`2,048` pages of `4,096` bytes).

Yours is a textbook example of an algorithm that cannot be tail call optimized. The result of the recursive call isn't returned directly, but rather, used as an operand for addition. Because of this, the compiler can't generate code to eliminate away stack frames during recursion. They must stay, in order to keep track of the addition that will need to eventually be done. This algorithm can be improved by using an accumulator parameter:

```
func sigma(_ m: Int64, acc: Int64 = 0) -> Int64 {
   if (m <= 0 ) {
       return acc
   } else {
       return sigma(m - 1, acc: acc + m)
   }
}
```

In this code, the result of the recursive call is returned directly. Because of this, the compiler can write code that removed intermediate stack frames. This should prevent stack overflows.

But really, you can just do this in constant time, without any recursive non-sense :p

```
func sum(from start: Int64 = 0, to end: Int64) -> Int64 {
    let count = end - start + 1

    return (start * count + end * count) / 2
}

print(sum(to: 50))
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to learn about more things than the superficial programming tutorials of iOS etc now, ie: computer science I suppose, so your answer gives me a lot of interesting information to take in and study further. My stack limit is indeed the default, so now I need to research further in to the stack `rlimit(rlim_cur: 8388608, rlim_max: 67104768)`

Comment: Yes, I figured this was more of an academic exercise than anything. Recursion is a giveaway :p

Comment: See my code edit, I show how to get/set the stack limit in swift

Comment: No need for recursion in this example, +1 for flattening the problem space.